# Scrolling panes with a header fixed vertically

Tags: html, css

I need a specific setup which seems to be difficult in HTML/CSS. I need:

- A header panel which stays put at the top of the page, filling the width available but also having a minimum width;
- A content page which can be scrolled vertically, and also has the same minimum width as the header
- If the minimum width exceeds the browser width then there should be a horizontal scrollbar which moves the header and content in sync (not independently)

This is what I have now. What am I missing?

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body style="overflow:hidden;position:relative">
    <div id="big-container" style="overflow-y:hidden">
    <div id="header" style="position:absolute;top: 0px;left:0px;height:80px;width:100%;min-width:1000px;background-color:blue">
        Header
    </div>
    <div id="container" style="min-width:1000px;position:absolute;top: 80px;left:0px; height:100%;width:100%;padding-bottom:80px;box-sizing:border-box;overflow:hidden">
        <div id="content" style="height:100%;width:100%;overflow-y:auto;overflow-x:hidden">
            <img src="http://www.fronetics.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/networking.jpg" />
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

(Yes I am separating out style and content - mixed them above only to keep the example short)

Comment: still a bad practice...

Comment: For starters you're missing valid HTML.

Comment: not sure what you mean by the 3rd point. for everything else you it's basic browser behavior, you don't even need to touch any css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `overflow` horribly wrong. Get rid of it completely. Set your img to the width of the container and make it rely on that and then set everything the same as you have it. Do not use inline styles. Even for displaying here. They are worthless and hard to point out.

```js
$(document).scroll(function(){
  
  $('#header').css('top',$(window).scrollTop());
  
});
```

```css
    #header{
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0px;
      height: 80px;
      width: 100%;
      z-index: 999;
      min-width: 1000px;
      background-color: blue;
    }

    #container{
      min-width: 1000px;
      position: absolute;
      top: 80px;
      left: 0px;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      padding-bottom: 80px;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    #content{
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
    }

    img{
      max-width: 100%;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="big-container">
        <div id="header">
            Header
        </div>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="content">
                <img src="http://www.fronetics.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/networking.jpg"
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: @DJClayworth you're not going to be able to do it with CSS/HTML alone. the only way to keep an element at top is `position: fixed` and that is designed to not allow scrolling left and right as well. SO if you want this you are going to need to use JS or some other library that allows a flow to be better. I use jQuery here because it can do the job with one line of code basically. Use this if you want to successfully do it.